# Finding function catching key event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events, keydown

I'm writing a user script for a complex web app.  The existing code is catching the 'j' and 'k' `keydown` events.

I'd like to be able to find this function to see what it's doing.  Is there a way to list all the key event handlers in a document? Or maybe a way to set a breakpoint somehow in Chrome Developer Tools for when I press the letter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in the developer tools, go to the *Scripts* tab, select the page, go to *Event Listener Breakpoints*, *Keyboard*, *keydown*.

[image]

Though this might not necessarily help you much, e.g. if the script is minified or they use a library. But you can give it a try.

Comment: Yeah you're right.  It's impossible to reverse engineer this nonsense :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a piece of your script to run first and if the keys are handled at the document level, you can install this intercept to see what part of the code is setting the keyboard handler:

```
var oldListener = document.addEventListener;
document.addEventListener = function(type, listener, capture) {
    if (type == "keydown" || type == "keyup" || type == "keypress") {
        console.log("type=" + type + " listener=" + listener.toString().slice(0, 80));
    }
    return (oldListener.apply(this, arguments));
}
```